# How to print out my Javascript variable as part of my HTML attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

### Details

- I want to convert address to coordinates
- I want to use that coordinate to populate a map view
- I know my `$coordinate` variable  = 42.6358311,-71.3290596
- I got that by simply running  `alert( coordinates );`

### What I have now

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address = "410 walker street Lowell MA 01851";

geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

    var coordinates = [latitude , longitude];



    alert( coordinates );


    } 
}); 
</script>
```

**Note** : 410 walker street Lowell MA 01851 -> 42.6358311,-71.3290596

```
<iframe

    width="200"
    height="200"
    frameborder="0" style="border:0"
    src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view?key=**********

        &center= 42.6358311,-71.3290596
        &zoom=18
        &maptype=satellite"

  >
  </iframe>
```

If I run this code I will get this result

[image]

So far everything work, you might wondering, since everything work why am I asking ?

Here is my question, rather than inputing the latitude and the longitude manually in `&center= 42.6358311,-71.3290596` I was wondering, if I can `print out` whatever stored inside my `$coordinate` variable.

Can someone please help me how to do that ?
I just want to print out my $coordinate variable as part of my HTML attribute.

Comment: Have a look to this API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start)

"Highlight a place or an address" gives me this result:

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=410+walker+street+Lowell+MA+01851
&key=..."></iframe>
```

Comment: Your answer is really elegant ! You save my life.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code snippet, may be this help you...

```js
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address = "410 walker street Lowell MA 01851";

geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
}, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        var coordinates = [latitude , longitude];
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 18,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
        mapOptions);        
        document.getElementById('myText').value = coordinates;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px; height:200px"></div>
<br />
<p>Print out your coordinate : </p><input type="text" id="myText" >
```

do you want to print out like this ?
Please correct me if I'm wrong..

Comment: maybe I missed it, but where should I place the api_key ?

Comment: just replace the script source with : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY

Comment: I still have a problem placing my `API_KEY` - Can you help me a little more ? I want to test out your solution also.

Comment: You can test this using Run Code Snippet..
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY"></script>

Comment: It work when I run the code snippet, but it doesn't work in my local env.

Comment: sorry, don't forget to use jquery bro to run this...
do you using jquery framework ?